# Hide Gridview Data but still accessible

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I use a gridview to query a DB and pull out results. The View then places the results in the view on the page. I then use a JS function to grab the data. Is there anyway  can hide the gridview but still have the data on the page html side?

Comment: Set `GridView.visibility = false`.  More needed to this question

Comment: I tried that but it hide the data from the html side of the page

Comment: then dont use that, use css and set the style display visibility. `display:none;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you mean "hide"?  You can always use CSS to set the display to none.  The GridView would still be on the page in HTML but not visible to the user.

```
document.getElementById('myGridID').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: can I do this from a js script?

Comment: document.getElementById('myGridID').style.display = 'none';

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `display: none;` rather then the visibility property of the gridview.